# Using Map returns empty object

Tags: node.js, json, nestjs

I need to use Map in my architecture. As you know Map can't be handled by `JSON.stringify` or `JSON.parse`, so we need to implement it by own.
Where and how it is better to implement it in NestJS?

Comment: in [interceptors](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) or [middlewares](https://docs.nestjs.com/middleware), I'd say.

Comment: I use microservices, and middlewares don't work there

Comment: Ok, so I use interceptor and before send response iterate an object to find Map and turn it to array of objects, and Transform to receive the object and turn it to map